# Fatal error after GitHub automatic merge

Tags: git, github, git-fetch

I have a repository on GitHub located [here](https://github.com/dapphp/securimage).  I created a working branch for someone and they forked the repo, made some changes on the working branch and submitted a pull request.

I tried the changes and everything was good and since GitHub was offering to automatically merge the pull request, I went ahead and click the big, green "Merge Pull Request" button.  All was well there except that the changes to the working branch were applied to the master branch which I can live with.

The problem is now that the repository cannot be fetched by me or anyone else.  I get this error:

```
dp@dpub:/tmp/gh$ git clone git://github.com/dapphp/securimage.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/gh/securimage/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 333, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (269/269), done.
remote: Total 333 (delta 91), reused 297 (delta 55)
Receiving objects: 100% (333/333), 3.91 MiB | 2.78 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (91/91), done.
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistant object 31d684d383913c4cf1a0d5ff0691c2c163284a35
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
```

This results in no directory being created or any working files getting downloaded.  I've searched all over for possible ways to resolve this but most talk about issuing commands to the git repo which I cannot do because I can't get a copy of the repo in the first place.

I've found I can still clone a remote branch using something like this: `git clone -b audiofixes git://github.com/dapphp/securimage.git` but I still get an error about the bad ref and I can't figure out any commands I can run to fix the problem.  I'm willing to undo the changes if necessary.

In case it helps, once I clone a different branch, here is the output of `git branch -a`:

```
* audiofixes
  remotes/origin/2.0.2
  remotes/origin/3.0
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/audiofixes
  remotes/origin/securimage_flash
```

At this point I really have no idea what (if anything) I can do to fix the state of the repository.

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:  Some command output as requested.

```
$ ls .git/refs/remotes/origin
HEAD

$ ls .git/objects
info/  pack/
# info is empty, pack has pack-b8add06e9a6864ea44a58c06b8bd549eedd90c94.idx and pack-b8add06e9a6864ea44a58c06b8bd549eedd90c94.pack

$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
cat: .git/refs/remotes/origin/master: No such file or directory

$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue you should contact GitHub about.

Comment: @Amber I sent a support request last night, no word back yet (not that I was expecting anything this quickly) but thought I'd try my luck with any Git wizards on here while I wait (im)patiently.

Comment: I'm curious: see if you can paste the results of `ls .git/refs/remotes/origin` and `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master` and `ls .git/objects`

Comment: @Thr4wn I went ahead and added the output of the commands you requested to the post, thanks.

Comment: You have the right approach now (get someone on github to fix the SHA1 associated with their repo's idea of `refs/heads/master`), but now I'm curious about exactly what went wrong.  There are basically two possibilities: somehow the new commit(s) went into the repo and left you with the branch-tip `31d684d...`, and that got written to `refs/heads/master`, and then the commit magically vanished; or, the actual new branch tip was something else but `refs/heads/master` was somehow written with `31d684d...`.  Neither is supposed to be able to happen.

Comment: @torek Everything was done "by the book" as far as I can tell.  My only thought as to how/why this happened was due to the fact that the merge was going from a working branch into the master branch.  I would have expected the automatic merge to merge the working branch from the cloned repo into the working branch of the master repo, rather than the working branch from the cloned repo to the master branch in the master repo (if that makes any sense).  That part seems to me to be the only strange part about the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEW:

Apparently 1) github does not give ssh access :(, and 2) it's impossible to share reflogs between different machines through git protocol.

So... You already created a ticket apparently, but you don't necessarily need them to fix the repository. All you need is for them (since they have privileged access) to run `git reflog master` on the server's repo and then paste the results for you to view. In that file, look for the previous SHA-1 value of master (since the current one doesn't seem to work). Once you have that, you (I think) can do the following (on your own computer):

```
$ git checkout -b temp
$ git update-ref refs/heads/temp $SHA1
$ git push -u origin +temp:master
```

This will undo the merge operation on the server.

You may be able to get the previously working SHA1 without having to get the reflog from the server. In your local repo (or your friend's local repo), the previously working commit *does* exist somewhere in there. If you can figure out a way to find it there, then you can proceed with the above suggestion.

OLD: Here is my first thought. If you are able to copy the `.git/logs` directory *from the server*, then that will have stored in it all the previous values of the `master` branch. Specifically, the file `.git/logs/refs/heads/master` will be a raw text file with the previous values of that branch. For example (I don't know if github allows you to do this or not):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dapphp/securimage.git -b audiofixes
$ scp github.com:/dapphp/securimage.git/logs/refs/heads/master .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master refs/remotes/origin/master@{1} #see "Date Spec" section of http://book.git-scm.com/4_git_treeishes.html
```

that should *theoretically* change the value to what master was previously. However it will only do that locally and will not actually change the value on the server, which is what we really need. So if you could ssh directly to the server and just run that last command there, that would (again, theoretically) fix the problem for good by simply undoing the merge.

.

This is all that I can think of on top of my head. But I really like solving git puzzles like this, so I'll let it sit in my head for a bit longer :)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I get an error trying to run the `scp` command.  I have to leave work at the moment and will try some again when I get home in a couple of hours.  I'm not sure what's happening but maybe github doesn't allow scp.  `Invalid command: 'scp -f -- dapphp/securimage.git'` `You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.`  The exact command was: `scp git@github.com:/dapphp/securimage.git/logs/refs/heads/master .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master` (no `-f` option as you can see).

Comment: Thanks for the help again, I kinda forgot about this after the weekend.  It was an issue with GH, apparently there was a small window of time where a bug caused some objects to get lost.  They were able to restore the repo to the state before the commit and then I re-pushed and all was good.  I appreciate your input on the matter!