# Git commands fail for some users, but not all

Tags: git, recovery

I am the Git admin in my dev group.

Recently, B was trying to do a `git pull` from origin resulting in many errors about  "refs/tags/... " and "refs/heads/..." does not point to a valid object.

So he tried to get a fresh `git clone` and got the same errors.

The same thing was happening for a couple other users, but not all, including myself (i.e. it all works just fine for me.)

After the attempts described below I tried to get the actual original error messages from B, but all he had was this tail of a long list of like messages:

```
...
error: refs/tags/v4.3.0_rev2664 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v4.6.10 does not point to a valid object!
fatal: failed to read object 0a628d61199464517a9baaa117092fdd73f2f362: Permission denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (10515 ms @ 01/04/2016 12:35:17 PM)
```

So we did some research and found this:

[Git refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14316087)

I followed the steps in that link on the remote repository (after making a backup copy) and things got better for some users, but not all.

Currently when B tries to `git pull` to his current repository he gets this message:

```
fatal: loose object b8ddd20da1655b990e361c720c2ee2e500d94bad (stored in ./objects/b8/ddd20da1655b990e361c720c2ee2e500d94bad) is corrupt
```

And when he tries to `git clone` he gets this message:

```
fatal: failed to copy file to 'C:\git_temp\v4/.git/objects/09/01785b71fddf0b5bcdb40e07dcd04f697d2576': Permission denied
```

Now when I check the remote repository folders, I find that `./objects/b8/ddd20da1655b990e361c720c2ee2e500d94bad` does exist, but `./objects/09/01785b71fddf0b5bcdb40e07dcd04f697d2576` does not.

When I do `git cat-file -p` on those files I find that they are valid recent commits.

As before, `git pull` and `git clone` work fine for me and for L.

I asked D to do a `git clone` from this repository and he got a bunch of `failed to stat ....` warnings, but it continued to create the cloned repository.

I'm at a loss where to go next to resolve this.

B has a bunch of code to push that we need ASAP.

Comment: did you check the file permissions on the .git directorie and files below? Are there user permission differences between you and B?

Comment: Do all the users have the same OS ? the same version of git installed (`git version`) ?

Comment: How is the central repo (the one you clone from) hosted ?

Comment: @ChrisMaes, B has normal permissions in his local repository folders. Just to be sure, I had B create an "empty.txt" file inside his .git folder and he had no problems. For the `git clone`, He had created a "C:\git_temp" folder first and cloned into that so there should not have been any local permission issues. I suspect the permission issues are on the remote end.

Comment: That was my question: are their permissions the remote?

Comment: @LeGEC, We all have Windows 7.  B and L and the server have "git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1". I have "git version 2.5.0.windows.1".  D has "git version 2.4.6.windows.1". A bit of a mess to be sure. 

The central repo is hosted as a folder on a shared drive. We access it as "//Build2/repos/dev/iras/v4.git".

Comment: @ChrisMaes, I just now had B create "empty.txt" in "//Build2/repos/dev/iras/v4.git/" and he was able to.  (I checked the properties of the folder and full permissions are granted to a "Domain Users" group, but instead of hounding IT to find out who is in that group, I thought it would be easier to test it by creating a file.)

Comment: @ThomasBates (trying to look at the permissions angle) I'm not familiar with W7 permissions on files. Does everyone one have the same access rights on all files in the shared folder ? Can you run an equivalent of `ls -Rl` (list all files with owner name and access rights) on the shared repository ? from your system and B's system ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like an access right problem.

Check that the user has correct access to the folders and files inside the shared copy of the git repository : from his system, open the git repo in the file explorer, and check if he indeed has access to the `objects` folder, to the `09/01785b71fddf0b5bcdb40e07dcd04f697d2576`, that no folder or file appears with a lock ...

My suggestion is : have everybody access this shared repo using the same user.

- either change the connection to the shared folder to use the same common user for everybody,
- or have everybody access the folder through an ssh connection, using one user account. This is as simple as :

  ```
  git clone ssh://user@host:port/path/to/folder
  ```